# How do display the firstItem/Maximal Price in Configurable products? Anyone? programmatically Magento 2.2.3

Tags: configurable-product, price, magento2.2.3

so I have Configurable products with associated simple products, and the Configurable product displays the least expensive simple product within each configurable product associated in Catalog.

So how could I modify that behavior to either show the FirstItem Price or the Highest price from the associated Configurable product within the Configurable Product, instead of the least priced simple product?

Here is a few screenshots of the problem in question:

[image: Catalog Configurable Products showing the least expensive Simple Product within the associated Configurable product in Configurable Product]

[image: How to Show programmatically the FirstItem price or the highest price found within a Configurable Product?]